# OpenGL - Moving Primitives along the X and Y using arrow keys

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, 2d

I'm building a 2D drawing canvas that allows users to draw shapes on the screen by first selecting which shape you want to draw, and then clicking into the drawing area to draw your shape. Here's what the UI looks like for a better visualization:

[image: 2D Drawing Canvas.png]

So far, I have some code that allows the user to click on the derired shape, draw the shape, then click on another shape to draw, and so on...

**First I check if a button has been clicked on in my** `processMouse()` **function:**

```
if (x >= 0 && x <= 95 && y >= 302 && y <= 380) { // area of SQUARE shape
    // squareShape = false by default
    squareShape = true;
}

else squareShape = false;
```

**If it has, we highlight the shape in my** `display()` **function:**

```
if (squareShape != false) {
        drawHighlight(100, 50, 350, true);  // highlighted SQUARE
}
```

**and in the same function, we enable some points to be drawn:**

```
if (areaClicked2 != false) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size();i++)
    {
        //areaClicked2 = true;
        glLineWidth(1);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(points[i].x + lineOffset.x, points[i].y + lineOffset.y);
    }
}
```

I have applied this exact same method for every other button, and they all seem to be working fine...

### My issue?

If I click on a button to draw squares, it draws a few squares, but when I click on an another button, my squares disappear because I don't have the square button selected. So for every button when I click to draw, the shapes are only visible until I click on an another button. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Everytime I want to make a new points vector for a new shape, I make a new vector like this:

```
std::vector <point> lines;      // old vector
point OnePoint;
std::vector <point> dots;       // new vector
point OneDot;
```

Should I not be doing this? If not, **how should I be**? I tried to keep `lines` and just make new `point` variables but then when I draw, they're exactly the same point.

Comment: The code you posted does not include the relevant parts. You probably wrapped it in an `if` somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm sure I just need code that displays each for loop whilst other buttons are being clicked

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I think you are clearing(or creating new) points[] collection on each shape selection. You should preserve old point collection and append new shape points so that it will be visible even on different shape selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late reply. I've updated my question just so you can have a look, would you mind showing me how to properly preserve old point collection and append new shape points?

Comment: Do not call  **`std::vector <point> lines;`** on each shape select. For testing you can make **`std::vector <point> lines;`** variable global(should be outside of functions) so that all of your points will be stored until exit.